# Cant edit Odoo website, i get UncaughtPromiseError > OwlError

Tags: odoo

Can someone help me with the following...

When i want to edit the website of odoo it keeps loading... when i use the pencil next to a menu item and try to edit it, i get the following errors

```
UncaughtPromiseError > OwlError Uncaught Promise > An error occured in the owl lifecycle (see this Error's "cause" property) OwlError: An error occured in the owl lifecycle (see this Error's "cause" property)
    OwlError@https://odoo.example.net/web/assets/251-7c5bc10/web.assets_common.min.js:1098:1
    handleError@https://odoo.example.net/web/assets/251-7c5bc10/web.assets_common.min.js:1105:101
    handleError@https://odoo.example.net/web/assets/251-7c5bc10/web.assets_common.min.js:1931:29
    complete@https://odoo.example.net/web/assets/251-7c5bc10/web.assets_common.min.js:1343:37
    processFiber@https://example.net/web/assets/251-7c5bc10/web.assets_common.min.js:1907:43
    flush/this.frame</<@https://example.net/web/assets/251-7c5bc10/web.assets_common.min.js:1903:109
    flush/this.frame<@https://example.net/web/assets/251-7c5bc10/web.assets_common.min.js:1903:87

Caused by: TypeError: can't access property "body", this.website.pageDocument is null
    setup/<@https://odoo.example.net/web/assets/285-63ebd6b/web.assets_backend.min.js:13355:672
    useEffect/<@https://odoo.example.net/web/assets/251-7c5bc10/web.assets_common.min.js:1939:145
    complete@https://odoo.example.net/web/assets/251-7c5bc10/web.assets_common.min.js:1341:196
    processFiber@https://odoo.example.net/web/assets/251-7c5bc10/web.assets_common.min.js:1907:43
    flush/this.frame</<@https://example.net/web/assets/251-7c5bc10/web.assets_common.min.js:1903:109
    flush/this.frame<@https://odoo.example.net/web/assets/251-7c5bc10/web.assets_common.min.js:1903:87
```

I have replaced my real domain with example.net for privacy

I have tried to regenerate assets in developer mode under tools hoping this would solve it...